# Open Office Calc setting an additional number format menu choice on the toolbar

Tags: openoffice

Is there some way that I can set a user defined number format (2 decimal place, comma separated thousands) as one of the formatting choices on my toolbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to write a macro to change the current selection to your format.  (The macro would have to test for the selection being a single cell vs a range as the required commands to change the format are slightly different in these two cases).

Once the macro was written, you can add it to the toolbar through Tools→Customize.

Answer (score 0):

The format you describe is already built in, at least in my locale.

1. In `Tools -> Customize`, select the `Formatting` toolbar.
2. Highlight `Number Format: Standard` and click the Add button.
3. Select the `Format` category and choose the `Number Format: Decimal` command.  Press the Add button.

Alternatively, use hotkey combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.